# c++ heap corruption when deleting char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, heap-memory, heap-corruption

why do i get heap corruption when trying to delete the char array.

The code below is in "main()"

```
case 'r':
        char *StrTReverse = new char;
        std::cout << "Enter a string: " << std::endl;
        std::cin  >> StrTReverse;
        std::cout << "String reversed: " << ReverseString(StrTReverse) << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        delete[] StrTReverse; <- Here the is the crash
        break;
```

below is the ReverseString function

```
char* ReverseString(char string[])
{

int StringLength = std::strlen(string);
char *NewString = new char[StringLength];

for (int i = 0, j = StringLength-1; i < StringLength;i++,j--)
{
    NewString[i] = string[j];
}
NewString[StringLength] = '\0';
return NewString;

};
```

I cant understand why this is happening. I am new to c++ so please take that in mind.
thanks for any help :)

Comment: Replace `delete[]` with `delete`. Also, you're probably leaking memory by using `ReverseString` the way you did.

Comment: thanks, also can you give me a direction to where it happens the leaking ofc

Comment: ReverseString allocates memory using `new char[Stringlength]`, yet you never `delete[]` that and loose the pointer to it by not storing the result of `ReverseString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *StrTReverse = new char;
```

You dont't allocate an array so dont call `delete[]` call `delete`

Replace

```
delete[] StrTReverse;
```

with

```
delete StrTReverse;
```

The rule is call `delete` on address returned by `new` &
call `delete []` on address returned by `new []`.

Comment: yeah, i didnt notice that it wasnt an array >_<. but even when i changed it to "delete" i still get corruption

Comment: @Xirox: Well as it seems you do need an dynamic array, so allocation should be `new []` and deallocation should be `delete []`, but i don't know why you are not using `std::string` to begin with.Using `std::string` is the real solution to your problem.

Comment: using std::string will solve my problem, but i cannot use it because its part of a homework that i am required to use an array of chars. also it didnt fix the corruption

Answer (score 1):

```
char *StrTReverse = new char;
```

This is not an array of chars. It's a pointer to a single char allocated on heap. In case of array you need to write something like this:

```
char* myString = new char[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

To point out something obvious:

```
char *NewString = new char[StringLength];
...
NewString[StringLength] = '\0';
```

If you allocate an array of `StringLength` characters, the last index you can legally address is `StringLength - 1` since arrays start at 0.

tl;dr: Allocate `StringLength + 1` chars.